# Add the ability to deactivate and reactivate accounts

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, linked-accounts

If you peruse any given SE site user's accounts page (mine included) there's a good chance you'll find that they are a member of a site in which they don't actively participate.  People often join sites out of curiosity or over-zealousness, but come to realize they really don't have anything to offer that community.  However, someday they might.

Currently, as far as I know, the only way to get out of a site is to ask to have your account deleted.  It would be nice if we could *deactivate* our own accounts.  This would remove them from the account list when others view your profile (perhaps even hide it from the owner also, in a collapsed region or something), thus reducing clutter.  Should we decide one day that we're ready to actively participate, we can reactivate the account and continue where we left off.  If the user has ever participated on that site, I think the account should still appear in the user list, but there would be some indication that the user is "on hiatus".  If they never participated, there's no reason for them to show up in that's site's user list.

Answer (score 7):

Uh... Just don't show up? I'm *rarely* on ServerFault, and my account reflects that: just look at "recent activity".

Not sure what this adds, other than a way for the folks who like to RAGEQUIT to do so without actually burning their bridges. You know, like the folks that quit Meta in disgust, leaving some snotty bio text, and then quietly show up a few months later and resume activity after the site fails to implode spectacularly upon their departure...

...Not that having an easily-queried list of such people wouldn't be somewhat amusing, but...

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/18393/cletus

Comment: I don't show up and no, we're not in dire need of this.  I'm basically just looking for a means to do some accounts page house keeping.

Comment: @raven: does the selective account association feature work? I haven't tried it, but I'm wondering if that wouldn't suffice to indicate that you've (at least temporarily) abandoned an account. Naturally, you could also leave a comment to that effect in your bio.

Comment: @Juan: Wow.  Some users really take these sites way too seriously.  Sure, they're fun and useful, but for Christ's sake, lighten up!  I was just suggesting an idea.  It will probably be ignored, but so be it.  You can't even hope for a feature to be implemented if you never ask for it.  The fact that so many users make these sites the focus of their lives is rather sad.  You know, like that guy who calls himself Shog9 ;)

Comment: @raven: yeah, that guy's nuts - these sites need some sort of marker for accounts like his!